# Concurrent memory access slowing down system

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, memory, concurrency

I have a particle system that needs to be visualized. But the visualization should have effectively no effect on the simulation itself. The current way this happens is by letting a second thread read the state of the particle system without any synchronization. This will of course cause the simulation to show some glitches but this is not an issue.

However what seems to happen is that the faster the rendered renders, the slower the particle system becomes. The measured time step of the simulation get spikes and almost doubles on average. I am fairly certain this is due to the renderer accessing the memory used by the particle system from a different thread.

Now the question is; is it somehow possible to disturb the particle system in a lesser extend? Accuracy of visualization is not an issue at all. I could theoretically imagine some way to instruct the compiler that the renderer is purely read only and/or that it does not need "recent" versions of the data. But i have no clue how to approach this.

PS. Language: C++, IDE: Visual Studio

PSS. Of course keeping the FPS of the renderer low already helps due to less memory access, but measured timed step of the simulation still spikes and slows down.

Comment: Why do you think this is purely due to memory access rather than the additional load from the rendering thread?

Comment: When putting the rendering thead in a busy loop without rendering (thus not accessing any data) the timestep is unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system slows down because when you just do a simulation, you data most probably is in cache level 1-2. The cache lines are in "Modified" state and every read and write to those cache lines is a cache hit with no bus transactions (i.e fast).

Once you run another thread accessing the same data, the changes made by the simulation need to be propagated to the point of coherency, so the visualization process (running on another CPU core) can read them. So the state of the cache line transitions from "Modified" to "Shared" state.

Then once the simulation thread want to modify that shared data again, the cache line transitions from "Shared" back to "Modified" state and a bus transaction generated, so the cache line in other caches gets invalidated.

So even reading from another thread slows down the simulation, because cache lines jumps between states and a lot of bus transactions is going on underneath. On Intel the cache coherency protocol is called MESI(F) and you can find more on that on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol

Regarding how to deal with the issue. Basically, you should avoid reading and writing the same data at the same time. It is hard, but you might want to consider the following:

1. You might try to modify the simulation, so it operates on two banks of data. One bank is to be used for simulation, while another is to be used to visualize previously calculated data.
2. You might try to simply copy the data in visualization thread in one go right after a simulation loop has finished. It will fix the glitches and it might improve the overall performance.

To synchronize between the simulation and visualization threads you should use busy waiting (like spin locks), not kernel objects, like mutexes.

All that said, there is no guaranty any of those techniques it will help in your case. It all depends on your data, CPU, cache sizes etc etc.

Comment: In your first option, I would imagine the simulation copies its state to the 2nd bank between simulation steps? (And does not actually 'operate' on it during simulation. Otherwise I do not see how that would help. )

Comment: I am not familiar with the algorithm, but simulation might write results to buffer 2 while operating on buffer 1. At the same time visualization might read buffer 1, so both threads read from buffer 1 and just simulation writes to buffer 2. Then we switch the buffers, not copy them, so simulation now reads data from buffer 2 and writes the output to buffer 1. So the visualization read from buffer 2 also. That is just an idea, it depends on your algorithm if it is feasible to implement...